# How to connect django and nginx with uwsgi?

Tags: python, django, nginx

i'm building web server with django and nginx, uwsgi.

I'm using macbook pro mid 14 , mojave

when i input port number, django works.
but without port number, it won't work.
i don't know what is wrong with my code.

```
uwsgi --http-socket 0.0.0.0:8091 --wsgi-file test.py
```

if i use this line, it works.
but

```
uwsgi --socket projectname.sock --wsgi-file test.py
```

like this, it won't work. i'm trying to solve this error couple times.
but it won't work

this is projectname_nginx.conf

```
upstream django {
    #server 127.0.0.1:8001;
    server unix:/Users/myname/Desktop/projectnae/name/projectname.sock;
}

server {
    listen 8999;
    server_name localhost;
    charset utf-8;

    client_max_body_size 75M;
    
    location /media {
        alias /Users/myname/Desktop/projectnae/name/media;
    }
    
    location /static {
        alias //Users/myname/Desktop/projectnae/name/static
    }

    location / {
        uwsgi_pass django;
        include /Users/myname/Desktop/projectname/fido/uwsgi_params;
    }
}
```

and this is projectname_uwsgi.ini

```
[uwsgi]

chdir = /Users/myname/Desktop/projectname/name/
module = projectname.wsgi
home = /Users/junbeomkwak/Desktop/venv/

master = true
process = 10
socket = /Users/myname/Desktop/projectnae/name/projectname.sock;

vacuum = true
```

Comment: why would it work without port if server port is not 80

Comment: which file? projectname_nginx_conf?